# Cannot assign to property: "description" property is immutable error with ( leftSwipe.description = .Left)

Tags: ios, swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am following along a YouTube video tutorial on Swipe Gestures. The code I am writing is exactly as being shown in the tutorial, but I an getting the error (Cannot assign to property: "description" property is immutable error) 
on the line (leftSwipe.description = .Left)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

var leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes"))

leftSwipe.description = .Left
 }
```

The tutorial author is writing it exactly the same way but not getting the error I am getting. 
I would be grateful for help. 
Link to the YouTubeVideo Tutorial I am following is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9r1UFNeVuFA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not `description`, you're using the wrong property name, it should be `direction`.

Comment: Thank you and I apologize for my silly question. I have realised I need to get my eyesight checked.

Answer (score 2):

is not `description`

```
 leftSwipe.description = .Left
```

it is `direction`

```
leftSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left 

// or use 

 leftSwipe.direction = .Left
```

Answer (score 1):

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{      
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:     
    Selector("handleSwipes"))

    leftSwipe.direction = .Left
 }
```

Comment: kiran -- I want to say sorry

Comment: Its ok !! but just do not pass harsh comments as i am just helping people.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 leftSwipe.direction = .Left
```